# Some device types cannot change focus mode on iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, camera

I have known that some AVCaptureDevice do not support changing focus mode, such as `builtInDualCamera`, `builtInDualWideCamera`, `builtInTripleCamera`. But what surprise me today is that `builtInWideAngleCamera` does not support such setting too.

When I try to check it out below, `builtInWideAngleCamera` returns `not supported`.

```
if device.isFocusModeSupported(.locked) {
    device.focusMode = .locked
    if device.isLockingFocusWithCustomLensPositionSupported {
        device.setFocusModeLocked(lensPosition: len)
    } else {
        print("not supported")
    }
} else {
    print("not supported")
}
```

But in Apple official app `Camera`, focus can be locked under zoom 0.5x (builtInWideAngleCamera). How can I do that?